# Conditional string formatter?

Tags: java, formatting

Is is possible to write some kind of conditional String formatter? So that if any argument is missing, the belonging string token is also neglected?

`String.format("first %s, 2nd %s", null, "2nd"); //prints "first , 2nd 2nd"`
But I'd like to get `2nd 2nd` omitting "first ,`.

Comment: Your best bet here is to use a `StringBuilder` and `if` statements to append conditionally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to code you algorithm - the formatter will not do this for you:

```
public String first(String s) {
    return String.format("first %s", s);
}

public String second(String s) {
    return String.format("second %s", s);
}

public String fmt(String... strings) {
    switch (strings.length) {
        case 0:
            return "Empty";
        case 1:
            return second(strings[0]);
        case 2:
            return first(strings[0])+" "+second(strings[1]);
        default:
            return "What are you doing!!!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
String.format("first %s, 2nd %s","", "2nd");
```

So the first one `%s` has ommitted.

Comment: This would still print `first ,` which - as you can read above - is my goal to be omitted.

Comment: to default this ability not supported and you must create a custom method with 'Object...' parameter for recieving number of '%s' and string manipulating in it method.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I can think of

```
String[] arg = new String[10];
arg[0] = "TWO";
    if(arg.length!=2)
    {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s TWO",(Object[]) arg));
    }

    else
   {        
        System.out.println(String.format("%s ONE , %s TWO",(Object[]) arg));
    }
```

You can also declare String1 as "%s ONE", String2 as "%s TWO" , check for the arg counts and append them into the finalString, and pass it in String.format(finalString,arg);

Answer (score 0):

One obvious approach is to have the value be the whole term.

Compare:

```
String.format("%s%s", "", "2nd bar");
String.format("%s%s", "first foo, ", "2nd bar");
```